# Visual studio 2017 debug console saying "ops"

Tags: c++

First off, i haven't been coding or using Visual studio for super long so please explain in details so i can follow. Thanks!

Every time i try to run any code i get the message "ops" in the debug window. I disabled my antivirus(windows defender) and reinstalled a bunch of times. I get the same issue using Visual studio 2019. Anyone have ideas ?

I tried a bunch of different codes and even the default hello world that the  Windows Console Application gives you isn't running.

Comment: ***Anyone have ideas ?*** No, I use VS 2019 daily on multiple machines for my native `c++` code  and I have never seen anything that said "ops". Same goes for 2017.

Comment: I use VS 2017 and have never seen that. Maybe a virus?

Comment: "reinstalled a bunch of times" - why would you expect that to change anything? I mean, one reinstall I can see the point of, but when that didn't resolve the issue, you did *more* reinstalls - hoping for a different result?? Why? Just doing random stuff for no (or unknown) reason is rarely the way to solve a problem.

Comment: -Jesper Juh

The point of the reinstalls were switching between 2017 and 2019. I have 2017 on my laptop and it works fine.

Comment: -macroland

I guess, i scan my pc once a month and i havent found anything. I dont see how a virus could be causing it though.

Comment: It may be time to reinstall your OS + Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Please check for the existence of one of the following registry keys.

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

If they exist and are not expected, please remove.  They may be created by malware, so you may need to use an antivirus product to remove the unwanted software.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Add a breakpoint at the top of your program.
- Step 2: Enlarge the tiny console window to a normal size.
- Step 3: Click "Continue" on the debugger.
- Step 4: "ops" turns into "To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops."